# transition expanding menu divs expand in nav bar but pushes other menu divs down when the window is resized

Tags: css, transition

Okay, so im learning html and css, so im relativly new to this. I have followed many youtube videos to create different layouts. However, I am having real trouble in with this particular tutorial that i followed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwe2zOz030o).
In this tutorial it shows how to make a really cool nav bar using the css transition effect, however, when the window is resized and i hover to expand a div it moves all of the other divs down the page. i want the divs to remain in the container at all times whatever the size of the window. i'm hoping this is really simple...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("styles.css");
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="#"><div class="menu">
<p class="p1">HOME</p>
<p class="p2">THIS IS OUR INTRO  </p>
</div>
</a>

<div class="menu1">
<p class="p1">GALLERY</p>
<p class="p2">THIS IS MY PHOTOGRAPHY GALLERY</p>
</div>

<div class="menu2">
<p class="p1">ART PROJECTS</p>
<p class="p2">MY ART COLLECTION</p>
</div>

<div class="menu3">
<p class="p1">CONTACT</p>
<p class="p2">CONTACT ME</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the CSS styles are...

```
a{text-decoration:none;
}
#container{
height: 125px;
width: auto;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
position: relative;
}   
.menu{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(139,62,181,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu1{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(255,153,0,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu2{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(53,108,255,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu3{
height: 125px;
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(154,44,21,1);
float: left;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.p1{
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
top: 0px;
left: 15px;
transition:all .2s ease-in-out 0s;  
}
.p2{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
position:relative;
top:0px;
left: 11px;
transition:all .2s ease-in-out 0s;  
}
.menu:hover{
width:900px;
}
.menu1:hover{
width:900px;
}
.menu2:hover{
width:900px;
}
.menu3:hover{
width:900px;
}

.menu:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.menu:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.menu1:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.menu1:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.menu2:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.menu2:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.menu3:hover .p1{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.menu3:hover .p2{
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Comment: This is more or less "responsive", i.e. it will adapt to whatever environment. For this, you need to either consider Media queries - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries or use percentages instead of fixed px widths (first one is much, much better)

Answer (score 1):

It is a good case to use "**flexbox**".
Please take a look at your code with implemented flexbox:
http://codepen.io/Nargus/pen/uymsI

I added only `display: flex;` and `overflow:hidden;` to #container.

Also added `min-width` for each menu item (the same as width) so that flexbox knows its limits.
Width in .menu*:hover may be as big as you wish, all extras will be cut by flexbox itself.

Flexbox is ok on all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox